# How to delete a row in ng2-smart-table

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I'm working on an angular project. I'm using `ng2-smart-table` as a table in my project. I already connect to `google cloud firestore` and now I can add and retrieve data with firestore. I want to make an option for deleteing the rows.
How can I do it?
I added the above mentioned table into manufacture component.

**manufacture.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ManufactureService } from './manufacture.service';
import { Manufacture } from './manufacture.model';

@Component({
selector: 'ngx-manufacture',
styles: [],
template: `
    <ng2-smart-table
    (createConfirm)="addData($event)"
    (deleteConfirm)="deleteData($event)"
    [settings]="settings"
    [source]="manu"
    >
    </ng2-smart-table>
`
})
export class ManufactureComponent implements OnInit {
    manu: Manufacture[] = [];

    constructor(private service: ManufactureService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        alert(this.service.show());

        this.service.getManufacture().subscribe(arr => {
        let manu_list = arr.payload.get('manufact');
        if (manu_list) {
            this.manu = manu_list;
        }
        });
    }

    settings = {
        add: {
        addButtonContent: '<i class="nb-plus"></i>',
        createButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
        cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
        confirmCreate: true
        },
        edit: {
        editButtonContent: '<i class="nb-edit"></i>',
        saveButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
        cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>'
        },
        delete: {
        deleteButtonContent: '<i class="nb-trash"></i>',
        confirmDelete: true
        },
        columns: {
        shopname: {
            title: 'Shop Name'
        },
        ownername: {
            title: 'Owner Name'
        },
        nic: {
            title: 'NIC'
        },
        contactno: {
            title: 'ContactNo'
        },
        address: {
            title: 'Address'
        },
        email: {
            title: 'Email'
        }
        }
    };

    addData(data) {
        this.manu.push(data.newData);
        console.log(this.manu);
        this.service.addManufacture({ manufact: this.manu }).subscribe(next => {
        data.confirm.reject();
        });
    }

    deleteData(data) {
        this.service.deleteManufacture();
    }
}
```

I can delete a whole document, but I only want to delete a particular single row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
deleteSpecificRow(event) {
    this.service.deleteTheRow(event.data.id);
}
```

I think you had already implemented a service (deleteTheRow) that delete a single row using id, i hope this will help!

**deleteTheRow() function :**

```
deleteTheRow(id) {return
   this.firestore
   .collection("yourCollection")
   .manu(id)
   .delete();}
```

- I guess you should take a look that at this :
https://itnext.io/how-to-crud-in-angular-firebase-firestore-456353d7c62

Comment: No I don't know how to implement the `deleteTheRow()` can you show me the function

Comment: look at this example it may help you : https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-ng2-smart-table

Comment: I want to know how to delete data which was stored in the firestore.

Comment: please review the anwser, i just wrote the "deleteTheRow() " function.